# Application doesn't work without Wi-Fi connection

Tags: android, connection, wifi

I've a question for you about the possibility to have an application crash if wi-fi is not able, I'm in the midle of the seea, or if it is diasbled:

My application permission about the net in general are:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
```

Some users complain that my app doesn't work if there's not wi-fi connection.

I never have experience about this issue.

Naturally my application doesn't provide only net services.

Thanks and regards

Comment: You can refer below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available

Answer (score 0):

You should allways check your network connection before doing network requests. To check if you have a netwrok connection you can use the following snippet:

```
    public static boolean isOnline(Context applicationContext){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try{ 
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe){

        return false; //Airplane mode is on
    }
}
```

Comment: I do it, but I'd like to know if some of you know if some phone carriers have inserted some limitation to external app to work, that use my net permision, if Wi-Fi is not present.